# host reveal.js slideshow from an amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, slideshow, reveal.js

I would like to host reveal.js slideshows from an amazon S3 bucket. However when I try uploading the files and navigating to the links, the pages do not render as expected. This remains the case even if I add the contents of the reveal.js github repo to the bucket also. I am using the `boto` python library to interface with the bucket and upload files programatically.

I'm sure it should be possible to host a reveal.js slideshow in this way. Is anyone able to spell out the process for me?

Thanks.

Comment: If your'e using Python I assume you already know the procedure for making S3 buckets accessible to the public, CORS, headers, and MIME (content-type). Can you post a url to the slideshow?

Comment: Ultimately I want to be doing everything directly with the python api. But so far I haven't even been able to do this manually with the aws console.

Comment: ...but so far I haven't even been able to do this manually with the aws console. I have made an example bucket at http://atester.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. It contains the contents of the reveal.js github repo, as well as two example slideshows that I would like to get working, and aren't at present. All files were uploaded and set to puiblic manually. Reveal.js is clearly working because when one clicks on the above link one gets the properly rendered reveal.js default index.html file (this is an improvement on my initial problem, but still not quite working for my own slideshows)...

Comment: ...the links for my two example slideshows are https://s3.amazonaws.com/atester/about_workdocs-cloudfiles__slides__2015-07-09.slides.html and https://s3.amazonaws.com/atester/tester_slides.slides.html. Neither of these are rendering properly as reveal.js slideshows. They were both made from ipython notebooks with 'ipython nbconvert --to slides'.

Comment: ok, a functioning solution: rather than using the reveal.js github repo, I add the reveal.js folder in the gh-pages branch of damian avila's scipy2013_talks github repo to the bucket. For some reason that works with my nbconverted slideshows.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: ? everything has changed ? Sorry disregard the second part of answer, I'm getting confused by all the changes... :-\

Comment: Well anyways, before everything started changing you had a link referencing `custom.css`.  `custom.css` either never existed or wasn't accessible.